# Adding a Comment to a cell in a macro

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I want to add a Comment to a cell in a macro. I have tried recording a macro to do it, but it doesn't do anything. Any ideas? Here's the meat of the recorded macro:

```
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:DrawEditNote", "", 0, Array())
rem dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertAnnotation", "", 0, Array())
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:DrawEditNote", "", 0, Array())
dim args4(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args4(0).Name = "ToPoint"
args4(0).Value = "$A$2"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args4())
```

Answer (score 3):

In OpenOffice it is called "Inserting Annotations"

```
' col, row - Zero-based
sub insertAnnotation(col, row, text)
    sheet = thiscomponent.getcurrentcontroller.activesheet
    cell = sheet.getCellByPosition(col, row) 
    sheet.Annotations.insertNew(cell.getCellAddress, text)
    cell.Annotation.isVisible = True
end sub

' row, col - Zero-based
sub removeAnnotation(col, row)
    sheet = thiscomponent.getcurrentcontroller.activesheet
    cell = sheet.getCellByPosition(col, row)
    cell.clearContents( com.sun.star.sheet.CellFlags.ANNOTATION )
end sub

insertAnnotation(2, 0, "Hello " & Now)
```